# How to make an aggregate query?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

There is an entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_pms_reservation")
@Data
public class TPmsReservation implements Serializable {
    .....
}
```

and there is the PanacheRepository associated to it :

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ReservationRepository implements PanacheRepository<TPmsReservation> {
    
}
```

With JPA we can make aggregate query like this :

```
LocalDate dateOccupation = (LocalDate) entityManager.createQuery("select MIN(dateArrivee) from TPmsReservation").getSingleResult();
```

So how to make it with quarkus ?

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#simplified-queries